# Webview with JavascriptInterface crashes when calling Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, youtube-api

I have an app with a webview which has a custom JavascriptInterface. the conenction is as follows:

```
class CustomWebView extends WebView{ 
   public void prepare(){
      this.addJavascriptInterface(new Interface(this.inner_c), "ifc");
   }
}
```

on the javascript a method is called from this Interface, which does the following:

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createPlaylistIntent((Activity) mContext, "key", "playlist");
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

as soon as the intent is called, the app that now is in the background crashes referring to a NullPointerException on the following line from another file:

```
public class MiscellaneousFragment extends Fragment implements PageActionListener
{
    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mContext = container.getContext();
        ...
    }   
}
```

How can I avoid the crash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `JavascriptInterface` is not executed in the main UI thread, while in Android some operations (such as updating a View) MUST be invokded in the main thread. So you can have a check in your JavascriptInterface to see if any code violates the rule.

Answer (score 0):

you  can use it add to you Interface.java

```
    new Handler.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
              Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createPlaylistIntent((Activity) mContext, "key", "playlist");
          mContext.startActivity(intent);
        } 
    });
```